# Excel VBA Index and Match

Tags: vba

```
Category     Fruits  FruitsPrice  Vegetables  VegPrice  Dairy  DairyPrice
--------     ------  -----------  ----------  --------  -----  ----------
Fruits       Apple   $1.25        Tomato      $0.99     Butter $3.45
FruitsPrice  Grape   $2.00        Potato      $1.45     Cheese $4.75
Vegetables   Pears   $1.75        Onion       $1.10     Milk   $3.55
VegPrice                          Cucumber    $0.75
Dairy
DairyPrice
```

I have the above table and 2 combo boxes; representing criteria 1) for "Category" (ROWS) and 2) for the "Items" under those categories (COLUMNS) and based on the 2 criteria in the ComboBoxes I would like to display the price in a TextBox using INDEX and MATCH if possible .

Can someone help me with the vba code.
Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me or teach me to code site. There are many free sites out there that will walk you through how to use vba and the basics. break your procedure down into steps and google each step. When you have code that just will not work and need help with a specific aspect of that code come back with the code and the problem.

Comment: Just about any of these [Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=hash+routine+library&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=excel+vba+index+match) will help you. I've found it best to write the `Match()` portion first, then wrap the `Index()` around it once that's working.

Comment: Here is my vba code however, it does not display the "price" in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I had a table prepared as per screen shot below and pulls Query from various columns and get result in Cell E5 (Output Value) by changing Inputs values in drop down list in Cells E2, E3, and E4 using formula below in E5 Cell.
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Vak.png)

[Query - Search Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRIiw.png)

Important - After writing formula in Cell E5 use your key Board keys. Holding CTRL+Shift keys and click Enter on your key board.